# Serialize and Deserialize canvas with image objects (Fabricjs)

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

i'm  using fabric.js to add image object to canvas. Serialization works fine, but after deserialization canvas object is empty.
console.log(JSON.stringify(canvas)) returns: {"objects":[],"background":""}

here is my code:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('goCanvas');

fabric.Image.fromURL("rooryteam03da088a.jpeg", function(oImg) {
        canvas.add(oImg);
});

var serialized = JSON.stringify(canvas);

canvas.clear();

canvas.loadFromDatalessJSON(serialized);

console.log(JSON.stringify(canvas));
```

I also tried loadFromJSON instead of loadFromDatalessJSON for deserialization, but with no result.
So, What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fabric.Image.fromURL` is async. You *stringify* the canvas before receiving the image, you should move that code to the image loading callback:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('goCanvas');

fabric.Image.fromURL("rooryteam03da088a.jpeg", function(oImg) {
  canvas.add(oImg);

  var serialized = JSON.stringify(canvas);
  canvas.clear();
  canvas.loadFromDatalessJSON(serialized);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(canvas));
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately nothing changed, after deserializing canvas is still empty.

Comment: You were right. console.log(JSON.stringify(canvas)) returned empty string because it must be written in callback function of  "loadFromJSON" like this: canvas.loadFromJSON(serialized, function () {
      canvas.renderAll();
      console.log(JSON.stringify(canvas));
 });

Answer (score 1):

The variable serialized becomes a reference to the object canvas.  When you call canvas.clear() you empty the canvas, and thus your variable serialized, which references canvas, becomes empty as well.

I'm not following what you are attempting to achieve since you are clearing the canvas only to add the same content back to it, so not sure how to offer an alternate option.

Comment: i removed canvas.clear(), created new canvas and tried  newcanvas.loadFromJSON(serialized), but nothing changed. then i removed adding image obj and just added triangle and it both serialization and deserialization warked fine.
                  
seems like i have problem with serializing and deserializing canvas with image objects.